# Newtonsoft Json DeserializeObject Complex Type

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I using the Newtonsoft Json library to serialize/deserialize json. For example say I have the following types:

```
public class Form {
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class FormParameters {
    public Form Form { get; set; }
}
```

Now say I try the following:

```
var ex1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject("{\"Id\": \"2\"}", typeof(Form));
```

It correctly deserializes the object. However I'd like the following to work:

```
var ex2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject("{\"Form\": \"2\"}", typeof(FormParameters));
```

The value from the form (2 in the example above) would map to the id against the Form property of the FormParameters class. Unfortunately the string passed into the deserialize method is fixed and I can't change it. Ideally what I'd like is to add an attribute to the Form property of the FormParameters class. Note that any solution must not break the first example either.

I hope I have explained this well enough. I'd really appreciate the help. Thanks

Comment: not sure I can discern the question

Comment: From the answer you've given it looks like you have an idea of what I'm trying to achieve. I've added a comment to help explain the problem a little better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done with a custom [`JsonConverter`](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/?topic=html/AllMembers_T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConverter.htm).  Here is what it might look like:

```
public class FormParamsConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return (objectType == typeof(FormParameters));
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        JObject jo = JObject.Load(reader);
        int id = jo["Form"].Value<int>();
        FormParameters fp = new FormParameters 
        { 
            Form = new Form { Id = id } 
        };
        return fp;
    }

    public override bool CanWrite
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

To use it, you can decorate your `FormParameters` class with a `[JsonConverter]` attribute like this:

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(FormParamsConverter))]
public class FormParameters
{
    public Form Form { get; set; }
}

public class Form
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

Here is a quick demo showing the converter in action:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string json = "{\"Form\": \"2\"}";

        FormParameters fp = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<FormParameters>(json);

        Console.WriteLine("Form Id = " + fp.Form.Id);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Form Id = 2
```

Comment: Thanks this looks like what I'm after. I won't be able to test this until tomorrow and if it works well then I'll mark this as the answer. Thanks again.

Comment: I've just got around to testing this and it worked a treat. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

```
var ex2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject("{\"Form\": {\"Id\": \"2\"}}", typeof(FormParameters));
```

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately I can't change the string which is passed into the deserialize method. I was wondering if there's any hook-ups inside the deserialize method like there is with asp.net mvc model binding which would allow me to customize the binding if it tries to bind against a property with a specific attribute.